# In Python 3.11 using ftplib and ssl I'm getting this error: ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2702), why?

Tags: macos, ssl, ftplib, python-3.11

Using Python 3.11.3 on MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 I've been troubleshooting an error I receive after successfully uploading one file using ftplib and ssl. I can successfully connect to the FTPS server but upon uploading one file the FTPS connection abruptly closes and I get this error in the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/MyBin/TTB/Python/ftplib_test2.py", line 67, in <module>
    ftps.storbinary(f"STOR {remote_file}", file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ftplib.py", line 508, in storbinary
    conn.unwrap()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1322, in unwrap
    s = self._sslobj.shutdown()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2702)
FTP closed
```

Here's my Python code:

```
import ftplib
import ssl
import traceback
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import socket
from pathlib import Path

# Set myPath and myPathLFTP to ~/Documents
myPath = Path.home() / 'Documents'
myPathLFTP = Path.home() / 'Documents'

date_input = "2023-05-01"
dt = datetime.strptime(date_input, '%Y-%m-%d')

f_mon = (dt + timedelta(days=0)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
f_tues = (dt + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y%m%d')

dir_week = (datetime.strptime(date_input, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

ftp_host = 'ftp.myftp.com'
ftp_user = 'myuser'
ftp_pass = 'mypassword'

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)

# Disable certificate verification
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
#context.options = ssl.OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION
#context.options = ssl.OP_NO_COMPRESSION

# Create an FTP_TLS instance
ftps = ftplib.FTP_TLS(ftp_host, context=context, encoding='utf-8')

# Set reuse_address to True
ftps.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

try:
    # Connect to the FTP server and login
    ftps.connect(ftp_host, 21)
    ftps.login(user=ftp_user, passwd=ftp_pass)
    ftps.prot_p()  # switch to secure data connection

    # Welcome message
    welcome = ftps.getwelcome()
    print(welcome)

    ftps.retrlines('LIST')  # list directory content securely

    # Specify the local file path and the destination file name on the server
    local_files = [
        f'{myPath}/{dir_week}/{f_mon}_audio.mp3',
        f'{myPath}/{dir_week}/{f_tues}_audio.mp3'
    ]

    remote_files = [
        f'{f_mon}_audio.mp3',
        f'{f_tues}_audio.mp3'
    ]

    for local_file, remote_file in zip(local_files, remote_files):
        with open(local_file, 'rb') as file:
            ftps.storbinary(f"STOR {remote_file}", file)
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()  # Print the traceback information
finally:
    ftps.quit()
    print("FTP closed")
```

Here's some info from the FTPS server:

```
openssl s_client -connect ftp.myserver.com:990 -starttls ftp
CONNECTED(00000005)
read:errno=0
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 297 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Start Time: 1685421631
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

I've tried uncommenting both these options to no avail...same error. So these options don't do anything for me.

```
#context.options = ssl.OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION
#context.options = ssl.OP_NO_COMPRESSION
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling ftplib. I've read through the https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html but I haven't found anything I'm doing wrong?

I was expecting to upload both the mp3 files in the list I provided but it stopped after one file and exited from the FTP with the error provided above.

Comment: This looks like a broken server which does not properly close the connection, i.e. no SSL shutdown before closing the TCP connection. It might also happen if the server has some problems. Check if the file is actually stored with the expected size at the server and if you have access to the server logs check for suspicious messages at the relevant time.

Comment: The file is stored with the expected size. I don't have access to server logs. I do know that when I use FileZilla or Transmit on Mac I don't have any issues. I might contact the admin on the server to see if something is in the logs.